# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'policy'

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I am trying to make an email script that can send an email. First, I made a Python script without any classes, just function just to make sure that the script runs as expected. After I got the expected result. I am trying to rewrite the script using classes, so as to learn. But I am getting error, which I don't understand. I don't understand where actually the problem lies.

Below is the code as well as the screenshot of the error

```
import smtplib
import os
import sys
import mimetypes #for guess mime types of attachment

from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

class Email(object):
  message = None
  subject = None
  from_address = None
  to_address = None
  body = None
  email_server = None
  attachment = None

  def __init__(self,from_address,to_address,subject,body,attachment,email_server):
    self.message = MIMEMultipart()
    self.message['subject'] = subject
    self.message['From'] = from_address
    self.message['TO'] = to_address
    self.body = MIMEText(body, 'plain')
    self.message.attach(body)
    self.email_server = email_server

    if attachment is not None:
      self.attachment = attachment
      self.attach_attachment()

  def get_message(self):
    return self.message

  def send_message(self,auth):
    username, password = auth.get_user_auth_details()

    server = smtplib.SMTP(self.email_server)
    server.starttls() #For Encryption
    server.login(username, password)
    server.send_message(self.message)
    server.quit()

  def attach_attachment(self):
    self.messaege = self.attachment.set_attachment_type(self.message)



class Security(object):
  username = ""
  password = ""

  def __init__(self,username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password


  def get_user_auth_details(self):
    return self.username, self.password

class Attachment(object):
  attachment_path = ''

  def __init__(self,attachment_path):
    self.attachment_path = attachment_path

  def is_directory(self):
    return os.path.isdir(self.attachment_path)

  def is_file(self):
    return os.path.isfile(self.attachment_path)

  def guess_and_get_attachment_type(self, filenamepath):
    ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filenamepath)

    if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
      # No guess could be made, or the file is encoded (compressed), so
      # use a generic bag-of-bits type.
      ctype = "application/octet-stream"

    maintype , subtype = ctype.split('/' , 1)

    if maintype == 'text':
      fp = open(filenamepath)
      attachment = MIMEText(fp.read() , subtype)
      fp.close()
    elif maintype == 'image':
      fp = open(filenamepath , 'rb')
      attachment = MIMEImage(fp.read() , subtype)
      fp.close()
    elif maintype == 'audio':
      fp = open(filenamepath , 'rb')
      attachment = MIMEAudio(fp.read() , subtype)
      fp.close()
    else:
      fp = open(filenamepath , 'rb')
      attachment = MIMEBase(maintype , subtype)
      attachment.set_payload(fp.read()) #Actual message
      fp.close()
      encoders.encode_base64(attachment) # Encode the payload using Base64

    return attachment

  def set_attachment_type(self,message):
    if(self.is_directory()):
      for filename in os.listdir(self.attachment_path):
        filenamepath = os.path.join(self.attachment_path , filename)
        attachment = self.guess_and_get_attachment_type(filenamepath)
        # Set the filename parameter
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = filenamepath)
        message.attach(attachment)

    elif(self.is_file()):
      attachment = self.guess_and_get_attachment_type(self.attachment_path)
      # Set the filename parameter
      attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = self.attachment_path)
      message.attach(attachment)
    else:
      print("Unable to open file or directory")

    return message



def main():
  #Constants
  GMAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com:587"
  FROM_ADDRESS = "xyz@gmail.com"
  TO_ADDRESS = "xzy@gmail.com"

  auth = Security("xyz@gmail.com" , "MySuperSecretPassword")
  attachment = Attachment("/path/to/attachment/file/or/directory")
  email = Email(FROM_ADDRESS ,TO_ADDRESS, "Hi from class Python" , "OOPs Python at Work!!" ,attachment,GMAIL_SERVER )

  email.send_message(auth)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

[image]

Comment: It's pretty much exactly as the error states. Paste generator.py in here.

Comment: String objects don't have an attribute named policy.

Comment: This is why I don't like duck typing + EAFP. I prefer to put `assert isinstance(msg, MIMEBase)` or `hasattr(msg, 'policy')` at the entrance of a public API instead of presenting users tracebacks like in this question. Failing early is better than debugging tracebacks like this one.

Answer (score 8):

I changed

```
self.message.attach(body) #In the class email constructor
```

to

```
self.message.attach(self.body) #In the class email constructor
```

and it worked.

I was attaching string type to message instead of MIMEText

Comment: True - Had the same error. Just use `msg.attach(MIMEText(str_text))`

Comment: what do we change in python3.7 for the above error? Which value in generator.py or message.py? any pointers